# How to retrieve element value of XML using Java?

Tags: java, xml

I am new to XML. I want to read the following XML on the basis of request name. Please help me on how to read the below XML in Java -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <Request name="ValidateEmailRequest">
            <requestqueue>emailrequest</requestqueue>
            <responsequeue>emailresponse</responsequeue>
        </Request>
        <Request name="CleanEmail">
            <requestqueue>Cleanrequest</requestqueue>
            <responsequeue>Cleanresponse</responsequeue>
        </Request>
    </config>
```

Comment: Err, this is very similar to your other question here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013687/how-to-append-a-new-value-in-xml-using-java/4013881#4013881

Answer (score 76, accepted):

If your XML is a String, Then you can do the following:

```
String xml = ""; //Populated XML String....

DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
Element rootElement = document.getDocumentElement();
```

If your XML is in a file, then `Document document` will be instantiated like this:

```
Document document = builder.parse(new File("file.xml"));
```

The `document.getDocumentElement()` returns you the node that is the document element of the document (in your case `<config>`).

Once you have a `rootElement`, you can access the element's attribute (by calling `rootElement.getAttribute()` method), etc. For more methods on java's [org.w3c.dom.Element](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html)

More info on java [DocumentBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html) & [DocumentBuilderFactory](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html). **Bear in mind**, the example provided creates a XML DOM tree so if you have a huge XML data, the tree can be huge.

- [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632043/how-do-i-extract-child-element-from-xml-to-a-string-in-java).

---

**Update** Here's an example to get "value" of element `<requestqueue>`

```
protected String getString(String tagName, Element element) {
        NodeList list = element.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
        if (list != null && list.getLength() > 0) {
            NodeList subList = list.item(0).getChildNodes();

            if (subList != null && subList.getLength() > 0) {
                return subList.item(0).getNodeValue();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

You can effectively call it as,

```
String requestQueueName = getString("requestqueue", element);
```

Comment: Why not use the built in Java SE XPath library?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076910/how-to-retrieve-element-value-of-xml-using-java/4077986#4077986

Comment: @Blaise Doughan, you could. I just used DOM to support legacy java that are still active out there.

Comment: Fair enough, if someone is still on JDK 1.4 then your approach is reasonable.  If they are on 1.5 or later then the javax.xml.xpath library is much easier.  I hate to see people doing things the hard way when a better way exists.

Comment: @Blaise Doughan, you will be surprised at how many companies (most especially banks) still run JDK 1.4.

Comment: Agreed there are developers using JDK 1.4, and that your solution is appropriate to JDK 1.4.  If, however they are using JDK 1.5 or above the javax.xml.xpath library is more appropriate.  There are many developers with JDK 1.5 and 1.6 as baselines.

Answer (score 38):

In case you just need one (first) value to retrieve from xml:

```
public static String getTagValue(String xml, String tagName){
    return xml.split("<"+tagName+">")[1].split("</"+tagName+">")[0];
}
```

In case you want to parse whole xml document use JSoup:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(xml, "", Parser.xmlParser());
for (Element e : doc.select("Request")) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: thanks for pointing to jsoup - vanilla java is pain in the ass here

Comment: Using first approach but getting ArrayOutOfBound exception

Comment: very efficient solution.

Comment: The first solution will behave incorrectly if input xml has [`<![CDATA[`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) blocks.

Comment: @Klesun Saying that it will behave incorrectly a bit bold IMHO. It will return the content of the tag regardless of what is inside the tag. What do you expect it to do?

Comment: @yurin Using first approach but getting ArrayOutOfBound exception up 2

Answer (score 29):

If you are just looking to get a single value from the XML you may want to use Java's XPath library.  For an example see my answer to a previous question:

- [How to use XPath on xml docs having default namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939636/how-to-use-xpath-on-xml-docs-having-default-namespace/3941277#3941277)

It would look something like:

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document dDoc = builder.parse("E:/test.xml");

            XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
            Node node = (Node) xPath.evaluate("/Request/@name", dDoc, XPathConstants.NODE);
            System.out.println(node.getNodeValue());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Required Node found NodeList on Node node = (NodeList) xPath.evaluate("/Request/@name", dDoc, XPathConstants.NODE);

Comment: can we achieve the same using JAXB?Will it be better than this approach?

Comment: Why are you casting to a NodeList but assigning it to a Node?

Comment: @RajeevM - It was a typo, it's fixed now.

Comment: @ziggy, XPath never existed in JDK 1.4.

Comment: sorry but this is a pain in the ass if you are trying this with soap messages (or xml with many namespace prefixes)

Answer (score 5):

There are a number of different ways to do this. You might want to check out [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html) or [JAXB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html). There are tutorials and the examples.

Comment: @sam: And you probably want to check this SO question as well, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558087/xstream-or-simple.

Answer (score 4):

If the XML is well formed then you can convert it to Document. By using the XPath you can get the XML Elements.

```java
String xml = "<stackusers><name>Yash</name><age>30</age></stackusers>";
```

Form XML-String Create Document and find the elements using its XML-Path.

```java
Document doc = getDocument(xml, true);

    public static Document getDocument(String xmlData, boolean isXMLData) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        dbFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        dbFactory.setIgnoringComments(true);
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc;
        if (isXMLData) {
            InputSource ips = new org.xml.sax.InputSource(new StringReader(xmlData));
            doc = dBuilder.parse(ips);
        } else {
            doc = dBuilder.parse( new File(xmlData) );
        }
        return doc;
    }
```

> Use **`org.apache.xpath.XPathAPI`** to get Node or NodeList.

```java
System.out.println("XPathAPI:"+getNodeValue(doc, "/stackusers/age/text()"));

NodeList nodeList = getNodeList(doc, "/stackusers");
System.out.println("XPathAPI NodeList:"+ getXmlContentAsString(nodeList));
System.out.println("XPathAPI NodeList:"+ getXmlContentAsString(nodeList.item(0)));

    public static String getNodeValue(Document doc, String xpathExpression) throws Exception {
        Node node = org.apache.xpath.XPathAPI.selectSingleNode(doc, xpathExpression);
        String nodeValue = node.getNodeValue();
        return nodeValue;
    }
    public static NodeList getNodeList(Document doc, String xpathExpression) throws Exception {
        NodeList result = org.apache.xpath.XPathAPI.selectNodeList(doc, xpathExpression);
        return result;
    }
```

> Using `javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory`

```java
System.out.println("javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory:"+getXPathFactoryValue(doc, "/stackusers/age"));

    static XPath xpath = javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    public static String getXPathFactoryValue(Document doc, String xpathExpression) throws XPathExpressionException, TransformerException, IOException {
        Node node = (Node) xpath.evaluate(xpathExpression, doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
        String nodeStr = getXmlContentAsString(node);
        return nodeStr;
    }
```

> Using Document Element.

```java
System.out.println("DocumentElementText:"+getDocumentElementText(doc, "age"));

    public static String getDocumentElementText(Document doc, String elementName) {
        return doc.getElementsByTagName(elementName).item(0).getTextContent();
    }
```

> Get value in between two strings.

```java
String nodeVlaue = org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.substringBetween(xml, "<age>", "</age>");
System.out.println("StringUtils.substringBetween():"+nodeVlaue);
```

Full Example:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String xml = "<stackusers><name>Yash</name><age>30</age></stackusers>";
    Document doc = getDocument(xml, true);
    
    String nodeVlaue = org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.substringBetween(xml, "<age>", "</age>");
    System.out.println("StringUtils.substringBetween():"+nodeVlaue);
    
    System.out.println("DocumentElementText:"+getDocumentElementText(doc, "age"));
    System.out.println("javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory:"+getXPathFactoryValue(doc, "/stackusers/age"));
    
    System.out.println("XPathAPI:"+getNodeValue(doc, "/stackusers/age/text()"));
    NodeList nodeList = getNodeList(doc, "/stackusers");
    System.out.println("XPathAPI NodeList:"+ getXmlContentAsString(nodeList));
    System.out.println("XPathAPI NodeList:"+ getXmlContentAsString(nodeList.item(0)));
}
public static String getXmlContentAsString(Node node) throws TransformerException, IOException {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    NodeList childNodes = node.getChildNodes();
    int length = childNodes.getLength();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        stringBuilder.append( toString(childNodes.item(i), true) );
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

OutPut:

```
StringUtils.substringBetween():30
DocumentElementText:30
javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory:30
XPathAPI:30
XPathAPI NodeList:<stackusers>
   <name>Yash</name>
   <age>30</age>
</stackusers>
XPathAPI NodeList:<name>Yash</name><age>30</age>
```

Answer (score 1):

following links might help

http://labe.felk.cvut.cz/~xfaigl/mep/xml/java-xml.htm

http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=25

http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=152

Answer (score 1):

There are two general ways of doing that. You will either create a Domain Object Model of that XML file, take a look at [this](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-xml/dom.html)

and the second choice is using event driven parsing, which is an alternative to DOM xml representation. Imho you can find the best overall comparison of these two basic techniques [here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0408.html). Of course there are much more to know about processing xml, for instance if you are given XML schema definition (XSD), you could use [JAXB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html).

Answer (score 1):

There are various APIs available to read/write XML files through Java. 
I would refer using [StaX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StAX)

Also This can be useful - [Java XML APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678894/)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using this for configuration, your best bet is apache [commons-configuration](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/). For simple files it's way easier to use than "raw" XML parsers.

See the [XML how-to](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/userguide-1.2/howto_xml.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can make a class which extends org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler and call

```
start_<tag_name>(Attributes attrs);
```

and

```
end_<tag_name>();
```

For  it is:

```
start_request_queue(attrs);
```

etc.

And then extends that class and implement xml configuration file parsers you want. Example:

```
  ...
  public void startElement(String uri, String name, String qname,
                           org.xml.sax.Attributes attrs) 
                  throws org.xml.sax.SAXException {
    Class[] args = new Class[2];
    args[0] = uri.getClass();
    args[1] = org.xml.sax.Attributes.class;
    try {
      String mname = name.replace("-", "");
      java.lang.reflect.Method m = 
            getClass().getDeclaredMethod("start" + mname, args);
      m.invoke(this, new Object[] { uri, (org.xml.sax.Attributes)attrs }); 
    }

    catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);    }

    catch (java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException e) {
      org.xml.sax.SAXException se = 
            new org.xml.sax.SAXException(e.getTargetException());
      se.setStackTrace(e.getTargetException().getStackTrace());
    }
```

and in a particular configuration parser:

```
   public void start_Request(String uri, org.xml.sax.Attributes attrs) {
     // make sure to read attributes correctly
     System.err.println("Request, name="+ attrs.getValue(0);
   }
```