# Grabbing values in XML elements in Java

Tags: java, xml

I'm looking into how I can get values from specific XML nodes in an XML file that I have. In my application, I have the entire XML file in a string, and I want to grab the specific information from there. I've heard a little bit about DOM and SAX, but I don't exactly know where to start. Any help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to retrieve element value of XML using Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076910/how-to-retrieve-element-value-of-xml-using-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the easiest ways is to use xPath. Here's a [tutorial](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2005/01/12/xpath.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can either use XPath ([example](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi.html)) or you can use DOM or SAX (as you mentioned) You can view my answer [here (how to retrieve element value of XML using Java?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076910/how-to-retrieve-element-value-of-xml-using-java/4076993#4076993) on SO.

Comment: link to XPath example is 404, can you add a new one?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is also Xstream 
http://x-stream.github.io/index.html

It let´s you do both directions (object to xml, and xml to object).
Here is the "two minutes tutorial":
http://x-stream.github.io/tutorial.html

Comment: JAXB is the standard for mapping objects to XML, check out:  http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-xstream.html

Comment: Well, he just asked for getting the content of an xml without an xsd or anything in an easy way, and I find it easier with XStream. Just giving one more option ;-)

Comment: JAXB does not require an XML schema, check out my blog for plenty of examples starting with POJOs:  http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/