# Getting element using attribute

Tags: java, xml

I am parsing Xml using Java, i want to parse element with the help of attribute value.

For example `<tag1 att="recent">Data</tag1>`

In this i want to parse tag1 data using att value. I am new to java and xml. pls guide me.

Comment: "pls guide me."  Please spell words properly.  BTW - did you have a question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are ways to do this. You can use either, xPath ([example](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi/index.html)), DOM Document or SAX Parser ([example](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=152)) to retrieve attribute value and tag elements.

Here's related questions:

- [Grabbing values in XML elements in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275341/grabbing-values-in-xml-elements-in-java/4275500#4275500)
- [how to retrieve element value of XML using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076910/how-to-retrieve-element-value-of-xml-using-java)

---

This is a workaround to what you requested. I would never suggest that type of "hack", instead, use SAX instead (see example link).

```
public static Element getElementByAttributeValue(Node rootElement, String attributeValue) {

    if (rootElement != null && rootElement.hasChildNodes()) {
        NodeList nodeList = rootElement.getChildNodes();

        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node subNode = nodeList.item(i);

            if (subNode.hasAttributes()) {
                NamedNodeMap nnm = subNode.getAttributes();

                for (int j = 0; j < nnm.getLength(); j++) {
                    Node attrNode = nnm.item(j);

                    if (attrNode.getNodeType == Node.ATTRIBUTE_NODE) {
                        Attr attribute = (Attr) attrNode;

                        if (attributeValue.equals(attribute.getValue()) {
                            return (Element)subNode;
                        } else {
                            return getElementByAttributeValue(subNode, attributeValue);
                        }
                    }
                }               
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

*PS:* Code comment not provided. It's given as an exercise to the reader. :)

Comment: Thanks for your replies. i want to parse the element which is having attributes. do you know how to do this..??? i am using DOM concept

Comment: Yes, if you have an `org.w3c.dom.Element element`, you can say, `String attribute = element.getAttribute("att");`.

Comment: Thanks again, ~ String attribute = element.getAttribute("att");~ from this i only get attribute(ie)whatever i given in attribute i can get it through String, but i want to parse the element with the help of attribute.

Comment: @HariRam, for this, you will need to use SAX Parser instead. DOM parser generates a DOM Document so getting an element and/or attribute requires you to know the name of the element and/or attribute respectively. SAX doesn't. It's an iterative parser and you implement how it should translate.

Comment: Okay, but i dont know Sax parser. can you guide me for this issue.

Comment: @HariRam, should I guide you in terms of SAX, xPath or DOM?

Comment: @HariRam, I added a code (**untested**) so feel free to hack away. :)

Comment: Why is this in any form a hack?

Answer (score 4):

This is java code to get the child node with given attribute name and value. Is this what you are looking for

```
    public static Element getNodeWithAttribute(Node root, String attrName, String attrValue)
{
    NodeList nl = root.getChildNodes();
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        Node n = nl.item(i);
        if (n instanceof Element) {
            Element el = (Element) n;
            if (el.getAttribute(attrName).equals(attrValue)) {
                return el;
            }else{
       el =  getNodeWithAttribute(n, attrName, attrValue); //search recursively
       if(el != null){
        return el;
       }
    }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a old question but you may use HTMLUnit

```
 HtmlAnchor a = (HtmlAnchor)ele;
 url = a.getHrefAttribute();
```