# How to parse xml element using attribute value

Tags: java, android, xml

How to parse xml element using attribute value. i am using Dom for parsing XML file. i am not sure for parsing xml element only having attribute value. is this possible in DOM..??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting element using attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093121/getting-element-using-attribute)

Comment: Actual guess for the question (including the duplicate): "How to find/select all elements in a XML document that have a given attribute value" ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following XPath expression will select all elements that have given attibute/attribute-value pair:

```
//*[@foo="bar"]
```

Example:

```
<root>
 <grand foo="bar">    <!-- selected -->
   <child foo="nobar"/>
 </grand>
 <grand foo="nobar">
   <child foo="bar"/> <!-- selected -->
 </grand>
</root>
```

Here's a [tutorial for the Java XPath API (jaxp)](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi/index.html). It has some snippets that show how to use it.