# Parse XML data from url using DOM Parser

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing, android-xml, domparser

I want to parse xml file from url :

http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist=cher&api_key=5d6ce941674603e4bb75cfad6cfa13b7

I want to parse following tags of the file :

```
<artist>
<name>Cher</name>
<image size="medium">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/64/62286415.png</image>
</artist>
```

But i don't know how to get the value of these two tags only.

I have tried the example code from 
http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/

But it does not showing to parse same tag having different attribute value. 
Can anyone guide me how this is done?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thankx. I solved my problem from this url :

[Getting element using attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093121/getting-element-using-attribute)

```
if(str.equals("image"))
         {
             n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);

             for (int i = 0; i < n.getLength(); i++) {
                    Node subNode = n.item(i);

                    if (subNode.hasAttributes()) {
                        NamedNodeMap nnm = subNode.getAttributes();

                        for (int j = 0; j < nnm.getLength(); j++) {
                            Node attrNode = nnm.item(j);

                            if (attrNode.getNodeType() == Node.ATTRIBUTE_NODE) {
                                Attr attribute = (Attr) attrNode;

                               if( attribute.getValue().equals("medium"))
                               {
                                   return this.getElementValue(n.item(i));
                               }
                            }
                        }               
                    }
                }

         }
```

Answer (score 2):

from the link you provided, I have just extract a small part :

```
    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("artist");
    // looping through all item nodes <artist>
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
       Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
       String name = parser.getValue(e, "name"));
       String image = parser.getValue(e, "image")); 

       //if you want the artist 'Cher' sigh ;)
       if (name.equals("Cher")){
          //do whatever you want
       }
    }
```