# XML to Hashtable

Tags: java, xml, hashtable, rft

Currently I have the code below to put the data in a Hash. 
My question: which value do i have to put in the part of !!!SOMETHING!!!. 
The code only has to read one elementtag and insert it's value in the hashtable.

```
public void ReadXML(){
    try {

        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(fileout);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        Hashtable hash = new Hashtable();

        NodeList dataNodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("DataArea");
//      getChildNodes().item(0).getChildNodes();
        Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
        String dataNodeIndex = root.toString();
        System.out.println("");

    for (int dataNodeIndex1 = 0; dataNodeIndex1 < dataNodes.getLength(); dataNodeIndex1++)
        {
            Node nodeName = dataNodes.item(dataNodeIndex1);

            if (nodeName.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element elementName = (Element) nodeName;
                NodeList elementNameList = elementName.getElementsByTagName(elementtag1);
                Element elementName2 = (Element) elementNameList.item(0);
                NodeList nameElement = elementName2.getChildNodes();
                System.out.println("NodeContent: "  + ((Node) nameElement.item(0)).getNodeValue());

            }
            hash.put(elementtag1, !!!SOMETHING!!!);

            System.out.println(hash);
        }       


    }



    catch(Exception e){ 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Comment: You could use `null`, though you're probably better off using a `HashSet` if your table isn't storing key-value pairs. [EDIT] Sorry, `null` won't work as a value for `Hashtable`. Use any object that you don't care about, that won't be a serious memory leak.

Comment: So what if i want to copy it all, I could break it apart myself. But i just need one good example to know what to do. i saw an example with accountinformation and transactions, but it didn't help me because i'm not adding anything up.

Comment: this code is messed up. what is `ElementTag1`? In java variables NEVER start with uppercase letters. your mistake is now fooling stackoverflow's syntax highlighter.

Comment: ElementTag1 is a global variable i put in, in the code it still accepts the tag. It refers to a xmltag name i defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use these method that i found :

```
protected String getString(String tagName, Element element) {
    NodeList list = element.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
    if (list != null && list.getLength() > 0) {
        NodeList subList = list.item(0).getChildNodes();

        if (subList != null && subList.getLength() > 0) {
            return subList.item(0).getNodeValue();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

use it like this :

```
if (NodeName.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
    Element ElementName = (Element) NodeName;
    Hash.put(Elementtag1, getString(Elementtag1, ElementName));

}
```

Check it out :

http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/

and

[How to retrieve element value of XML using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076910/how-to-retrieve-element-value-of-xml-using-java/4076993#4076993)

Answer (score 0):

You have chosen incorrect collection type for this operation, if you wanna save your element tag values in `Set` yes it is better to use `HashSet` but implementation of `HashSet` approximately you try to do, so values of `Set` puts into `HashMap` like keys, but you can use another collection like `List`, `Queue`, `Stack` try to find better for you. 
And maybe `SAX` will be better `DOM` for you ...

Answer (score 0):

To make things easier and more robust, you could use a [Properties](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) instead, which has an underlying implementation of a [Hashtable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) (it actually extends it) and can import and export to/from XML (see `loadFromXML` and `storeToXML` methods). See http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-tiger02254/index.html for details.