# XML Parsing with Java: <element name ="doctype">

Tags: java, xml, parsing, elementname

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to retrieve element value of XML using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076910/how-to-retrieve-element-value-of-xml-using-java)

I am trying to parse a xml file with java using dom.
The xml looks like this:

```
<documents>
  <document>
    <element name="doctype">
      <value>Circular</value>
    </element>
  </document>
</documents>
```

Geting the root node "documents" and also the child node "document" is easy. But I can't get the value of the element with the name "doctype" (I want to store the value "Circular" in a database). Can someone help me please?

Comment: Why can you not get that element? Show us your code.

Comment: doc.getElementsByTagName("document").item(0).getNodeName()

doc is my documentbuilder, with whom I parsed the xml file.
If I print this, the knot "document" will be displayed. But I dont know how to get the element values.

Comment: Sorry but this did not really help

Comment: If I wirite this: 
System.out.println(doc.getElementsByTagName("data").item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());
A Nullpointerexeption comes out

Comment: I recommend using the XPath APIs included in Java SE 5 instead of the DOM APIs:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/4077986/383861

Comment: I am sorry but I dont want to restrcuture my whole project. Maybe this is easier but isnt there an easy way with DOM?

Comment: You can issue the XPath statement right against the DOM you currently have.  No need to restructure anything.

Comment: I tried this:
XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        Node node = null;
  try {
   node = (Node) xPath.evaluate("/element/doctype", doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
  } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
        System.out.println(node.getNodeValue());

But then I get a nullpointer exeption:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following XPath to get the data you are looking for:

```
/documents/document/element[@name='doctype']/value
```

**Demo**

The following demo code demonstrates how to execute that XPath against your DOM.  This application will run in any standard Java SE 5 (or newer) install.

```
package forum11578831;

import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document dDoc = builder.parse("src/forum11578831/input.xml");

        XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        String string = (String) xPath.evaluate("/documents/document/element[@name='doctype']/value", dDoc, XPathConstants.STRING);
        System.out.println(string);
    }

}
```

**input.xml**

I have expanded the XML document to contain `element` elements with `name` attributes with values other that `doctype` to demonstrate that the XPath works.

```
<documents>
  <document>
    <element name="foo">
      <value>FOO</value>
    </element>
    <element name="doctype">
      <value>Circular</value>
    </element>
    <element name="bar">
      <value>BAR</value>
    </element>
  </document>
</documents>
```

**Output**

The result of executing the XPath is the very `String` you are looking for:

```
Circular
```

Comment: Thank you very much, not it works fine. You saved me a lot of time!!!