# How to get values of all elements from XML string in Java?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I have the a string in XML format. I want to read it and get the values of the elements.

I have tried Java [JAXBContext unmarshell](http://rocksolutions.wordpress.com/2010/08/10/jaxb-unmarshalling-strings-xmls/), but this needs creation of class which is not necessary for me.

String:

```
<customer>
    <age>35</age>
    <name>aaa</name>
</customer>
```

I want to get the values of **age** and **name**.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to retrieve element value of XML using Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076910/how-to-retrieve-element-value-of-xml-using-java)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

This is your xml:

```
String xml = "<customer><age>35</age><name>aaa</name></customer>";
```

And this is the parser:

```
DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
InputSource src = new InputSource();
src.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));

Document doc = builder.parse(src);
String age = doc.getElementsByTagName("age").item(0).getTextContent();
String name = doc.getElementsByTagName("name").item(0).getTextContent();
```

Comment: Sr but how to fix error at builder.parse(src): `No signature of method: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse() is applicable for argument types: (jdk.internal.org.xml.sax.InputSource) values: [jdk.internal.org.xml.sax.InputSource@4398571a]\nPossible solutions: parse(java.io.File), parse(java.io.InputStream), parse(java.lang.String), parse(org.xml.sax.InputSource), parse(org.xml.sax.InputSource), parse(java.io.InputStream, java.lang.String)`

Comment: You probably imported `jdk.internal.org.xml.sax.InputSource` instead of `org.xml.sax.InputSource`

Comment: Thank you, I'm new to Java and it's hard to search which library should be imported for one class.

Answer (score 11):

[JSoup](http://www.jsoup.org) has a nice support for XML

```
import org.jsoup.*     
import org.jsoup.nodes.*   
import  org.jsoup.parser.*

//str is the xml string 
String str = "<customer><age>35</age><name>aaa</name></customer>"
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(str, "", Parser.xmlParser());
System.out.println(doc.select("age").text())
```

Answer (score 7):

Using [XPath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html) in the standard API:

```
String xml = "<customer>" + "<age>35</age>" + "<name>aaa</name>"
    + "</customer>";
InputSource source = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance()
                          .newXPath();
Object customer = xpath.evaluate("/customer", source, XPathConstants.NODE);
String age = xpath.evaluate("age", customer);
String name = xpath.evaluate("name", customer);
System.out.println(age + " " + name);
```

Answer (score 2):

[JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/) is quite easy to use:

```
SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
File xmlFile = new File("c:\\file.xml");
Document document = (Document) builder.build(xmlFile);
Element rootNode = document.getRootElement();
List list = rootNode.getChildren("customer");

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

    Element node = (Element) list.get(i);

    System.out.println("Age : " + node.getChildText("age"));
    System.out.println("Name : " + node.getChildText("name"));         
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as a tidbit for users with more COMPLICATED XMLs, as I do. If you have elements with the same name but, different attributes, for example:

```
<field tag="8"> Country </field>
<field tag="12"> State </field>
```

The way to extract them is to follow @vault's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14159232/1292323) but, make sure to change the value in the `.item(int)` function.

If you want the first field you use `.item(0)`. If you want the second you use `.item(1)`

Hope this helps for future users as it did for me.

Answer (score 0):

I iterate over all elements with this generic method:

```
public static void getElementValues(Node node) {
    NodeList nodeList = node.getChildNodes();
    for (int i = 0, len = nodeList.getLength(); i < len; i++) {
        Node currentNode = nodeList.item(i);
        if (len == 1 && currentNode.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
            System.out.println(node.getLocalName() + "=" + currentNode.getTextContent());
        }
        else if (currentNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            getElementValues(currentNode);
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
age = 35
name = aaa
```