# XML in Java: Get values from specific elements

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have a question concering the returning of values from deep within a xml structure.
First, here's the xml-code:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <log>
    <published>2014-03-28T15:28:36.646Z</published>
    <actor>
        <objectType>person</objectType>
        <id>e1b8948f-321e-78ca-d883-80500aae71b5</id>
        <displayName>anonymized</displayName>
    </actor>
    <verb>update</verb>
    <object>
        <objectType>concept</objectType>
        <id>a1ad6ace-c722-ffa9-f58e-b4169acdb4e3</id>
        <content>time</content>
    </object>
    <target>
        <objectType>conceptMap</objectType>
        <id>4b8f69e3-2914-3a1a-454e-f4c157734bd1</id>
        <displayName>my first concept map</displayName>
    </target>
    <generator>
        <objectType>application</objectType>
        <url>http://www.golabz.eu/content/go-lab-concept-mapper</url>
        <id>c9933ad6-dd4a-6f71-ce84-fb1676ea3aac</id>
        <displayName>ut.tools.conceptmapper</displayName>
    </generator>
    <provider>
        <objectType>ils</objectType>
        <url>http://graasp.epfl.ch/metawidget/1/b387b6f</url>
        <id>10548c30-72bd-0bb3-33d1-9c748266de45</id>
        <displayName>unnamed ils</displayName>
    </provider>
    </log>`

I found a method here at Stackoverflow which deals with that ([How to retrieve element value of XML using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076910/how-to-retrieve-element-value-of-xml-using-java)):

```
protected String getString(String tagName, Element element) {
    NodeList list = element.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
    if (list != null && list.getLength() > 0) {
        NodeList subList = list.item(0).getChildNodes();

        if (subList != null && subList.getLength() > 0) {
            return subList.item(0).getNodeValue();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

My problem is that I don't know how to get a specific ID (or the value of an other element) with that method WITHOUT using explicit pre-defined methods (I want to pass the ID I look for in the method-head itself).
If I use `getString("id", document.getDocumentElement)` it returns just the "e1b8948f-321e-78ca-d883-80500aae71b5"-ID. What to do if I want to get the ID "a1ad6ace-c722-ffa9-f58e-b4169acdb4e3" which is a subnode from `<object>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an XPath expression for this.

```
XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xPath = xPathFactory.newXPath();
XPathExpression xPathExpression = xPath.compile("//object/id");

// this should return one "id" node
NodeList idNodelist = (NodeList) xPathExpression.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
Node idNode = idNodelist.item(0);
System.out.println(idNode.getTextContent());
```

Comment: Never heard of XPath before. How can I access to the value within? If I write `idNodeList.item(0).getNodeValue()` it just returns "null".

Comment: @X-Fate Updated. The text you want to retrieve is the child node of the "id" element node.

Comment: Great! With `getTextContent` the value is returned. Thanks! Problem solved... I guess... :p

Comment: Yes you can use that as well.