# Remove whitespace within XML fields using Java

Tags: java, xml, whitespace, nsxmlparser, removing-whitespace

I'm facing an issue with removing whitespaces within the value fields in the xml data.

eg:

Input

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ns:myOrder xmlns:ns="http://w3schools.com/BusinessDocument" xmlns:ct="http://something.com/CommonTypes">
  <MessageHeader>
     <ct:ID>i7                           </ct:ID>
     <ct:ID>i7                           </ct:ID>
     <ct:ID>i7                           </ct:ID>
     <ct:ID>i7                           </ct:ID>
     <ct:Name> Company Name           </ct:Name>
 </MessageHeader>
</ns:myOrder>
```

Expected output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <ns:myOrder xmlns:ns="http://w3schools.com/BusinessDocument" xmlns:ct="http://something.com/CommonTypes">
    <MessageHeader>
       <ct:ID>i7</ct:ID>
       <ct:ID>i7</ct:ID>
       <ct:ID>i7</ct:ID>
       <ct:ID>i7</ct:ID>
       <ct:Name>Company Name</ct:Name>
    </MessageHeader>
  </ns:myOrder>
```

I tried with the below code

```
public static String getTrimmedXML(String rawXMLFilename) throws Exception
     {
          BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(rawXMLFilename));
     String str;
     String trimmedXML = null;     
     while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) 
     {
          String str1 = str;
          if (str1.length()>0) 
          {
               str1 = str1.trim();
               if(str1.charAt(str1.length()-1) == '>')
               {
                    trimmedXML = trimmedXML + str.trim();
               }
               else
               {
                    trimmedXML = trimmedXML + str;
               }
          }
     }     
     in.close();
     return trimmedXML.substring(4);
     }
```

I'm unable to remove those spaces. Please let me know where i'm going wrong

Regards,
Monish

Comment: `trim` only remove spaces at the start and the end of a string (in your case a line). Try to parse the XML remove the spaces and rewrite the XML.

Comment: The xpath function `normalize-space` will do this trimming. You can use a [modified `Identity transform`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) to do this in XSL.

Comment: If one of the answers helped you solve the issue, you can check the checkmark on it. This also gives you some additional reputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might not want to use replace or replace all because then it will replace all whitespace in your xml data. If you want to trim start/end of xml content, either you want to parse the whole xml or using xpath and transform it back to string. Use below's code.

```
public static String getTrimmedXML(String rawXMLFilename, String tagName) throws Exception {
    // Create xml document object
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(rawXMLFilename));
    InputSource source = new InputSource(in);
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = db.parse(source);
    XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();

    // Path to the node that you want to trim
    NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xpath.compile("//*[name()='" + tagName + "']").evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    for (int index = 0; index < nodeList.getLength(); index++) { // Loop through all nodes that match the xpath
        Node node = nodeList.item(index);
        String newTextContent = node.getTextContent().trim(); // Actual trim process
        node.setTextContent(newTextContent);
    }

    // Transform back the document to string format.
    TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    transformer.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(writer));
    String output = writer.getBuffer().toString().replaceAll("\n|\r", "");
    return output;
}
```

Comment: what if there are multiple tags apart from 'ct:ID'? How do I define for other tags. Kindly let me know. Regards, Monish

Comment: You edit the function to accept another parameter  which is the xpath string and provide the path of the node that u want to trim to that function.

Comment: Ive edited the answer to make it reusable for other tag as well.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code that does white space removal in vtd-xml.

```
import com.ximpleware.*;
public class removeWS {

    public static void main(String[] s) throws VTDException, Exception{
        VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
        AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot();
        XMLModifier xm = new XMLModifier();
        if (vg.parseFile("d:\\xml2\\ws.xml", true)){
            VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
            ap.bind(vn);
            xm.bind(vn);
            ap.selectXPath("//text()");
            int i=-1;
            while((i=ap.evalXPath())!=-1){
                int offset = vn.getTokenOffset(i);
                int len = vn.getTokenLength(i);

                long l = vn.trimWhiteSpaces((((long)len)<<32)|offset );
                System.out.println(" ===> "+vn.toString(i));
                System.out.println("len ==>"+len+" new len==>"+ (l>>32));
                int nlen = (int)(l>>32);
                int nos= (int) l;
                xm.updateToken(i,vn,nos,nlen);
            }
            xm.output("d:\\xml2\\new.xml");

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you should use [a XML library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5059411/4136325), then probably select the affected [Nodes via XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4077986/4136325), and then

```
String value = node.getTextContent();
node.setTextContent(value.trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing all whitespaces in a string can be done with the String class's replace method like so:

```
String str = " random    message withlots   of white  spaces     ";
str = str.replace(" ", "");
System.out.println(str);
```

The above will run to print str without any whitespaces.  The replace method takes 2 arguments- the first is the String you want the method to replace by the second argument- which is another String.  This method's arguments are not limited to single-character Strings either.

Answer (score -3):

Use replaceAll method in java

for Example

```
String s1 = "<ct:ID>i7                           </ct:ID>";
System.out.println(s1.replaceAll(" ","").trim());
```

Comment: That would remove spaces inside the XML, so if a tag read something like 
`<field name="Version Date">
                        <value>03/15/2017     </value>
                     </field>`,  that would turn the attribute "Version Date" into "VersionDate".  A correct solution will not alter the XML.