# How to get selected characters from xm parsing in java

Tags: java, xml, parsing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<digitalObjectWrapper>
<count>1</count>
<entities>
  <entity>
     <baseId>24</baseId>
     <startDate>2015-09-02T19:06:08.839+02:00</startDate>
     <endDate>2015-09-07T14:33:46.909+02:00</endDate>
     <note>Ingest1</note>
  </entity>
</entities>
</digitalObjectWrapper>
```

This is my xml data and from this tag `<startDate>2015-09-02T19:06:08.839+02:00</startDate>` i just want `2015-09-02 19.06` while parsing.

How can i achieve that ?

Comment: You should not mix parsing XML and business logic. First, parse correctly the XML, storing the `startDate` and `endDate` in `Date` objects. Then, apply your business logic to discard seconds and milliseconds.

Comment: please make a search.

check this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076910/how-to-retrieve-element-value-of-xml-using-java

Comment: i have parsed the data but it all comes as one string.....i need to delete some characters from the string.

Comment: and this does not only contain seconds n millisec it has GMT and a letter T in between

Answer (score 0):

Keep two static final format strings i.e. one for source format another for target format.
Once reading this date string from xml, convert to target format using simpledateformat.