# Regular expression with xml tag

Tags: java, regex, xml

I have this XML string:

```
   <TransactionId>1231231</TransactionId>
   <TransactionDescription>Card was succesfully created: DDCARD-26913899</TransactionDescription>
   <Error>00</Error>
   <ExpiryDate>1084412</ExpiryDate>
```

I need to extract the string after the colon( which is unique) and containing the number, in this case (DDCARD-26913899).
  The string after the value i want to extract is an XML tag and can be any other tag other than TransactionDescription.

I want to do it by using regular expression in Java , but i don't know how.
  Appreciate any help

Comment: Don't parse XML using regex; use a real parser.  See [**How to retrieve element value of XML using Java?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076910/how-to-retrieve-element-value-of-xml-using-java) or  [**How to read XML using XPath in Java**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811001/how-to-read-xml-using-xpath-in-java)

Comment: yes, this can be a solution.thanks