# regex to find xml element & replace

Tags: regex, xml, replace, find

I have a xml file with this data format

```
    <row Id="9" Body="aaaaaaaaa" Target="123456" />
```

I want to find & replace all `Body=""` things with a space from my xml file. What is the regex for that?

Comment: Don't parse XML using regex; use a real parser.  See [**How to retrieve element value of XML using Java?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076910/how-to-retrieve-element-value-of-xml-using-java) or  [**How to read XML using XPath in Java**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811001/how-to-read-xml-using-xpath-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many possibilities, here is one way to remove the content from the `Body` attribute

```
(<row.*Body=").*?("[^>]+>)
```

This creates two capturing groups for the content before and after the `Body` attribute. Then, you just use those capturing groups for the replacement:

```
$1$2
```

It will transform:

```
<row Id="9" Body="aaaaaaaaa" Target="123456" />
```

Into:

```
<row Id="9" Body="" Target="123456" />
```

You can see it working [here](https://regex101.com/r/k2Y5zN/1).

Comment: Can you give a regex only to find that element?? I can replace it by my text editor

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. You only want to find one element? With what characteristics? From your question it seems like you want to find all elements with an empty `Body` attribute.

Comment: Yes that's what I wanted. I have a data set of more than 20GB. That's why I wanted to remove this Body element data. I tried your answer with a text editor, but didn't work

Comment: Oh okay, I think I understand - Like this? https://regex101.com/r/k2Y5zN/1 In the Substitution panel, I used `$1$2` as the replacement, so you can see that it turned `<row Id="9" Body="aaaaaaaaa" Target="123456" />` into `<row Id="9" Body="" Target="123456" />`

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. It's great if you can edit the answer with this code as well