# Replacing xml tag value by regex

Tags: regex, xml, apache-nifi

I have xml like this and i want to  replace carrot tag  value  by something else  i use  this  expression `(<.[^(><.)]+>)` but it  doesn't  work properly what  should  i change to manage getting  value and  replacing it  with new  value?:

```
<Monkey xmlns="http://urlhere.com/monkeynamespace">
 <foodType>
  <vegtables>
   <carrots>1</carrots>
  </vegtables>
 <foodType>   
</Monkey>
```

Comment: [**TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1954610)

Comment: Use an XML parser. Not regex. What language are you using?

Comment: i  want to make it in nifi replaceText processor  and  it doesn't  support xpath i, i  use java

Comment: Don't parse XML using regex; use a real XML parser.  See [**How to retrieve element value of XML using Java?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076910/how-to-retrieve-element-value-of-xml-using-java) or  [**How to read XML using XPath in Java**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811001/how-to-read-xml-using-xpath-in-java)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use a [positive lookahead and a positive lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Example:

```
(?<=<carrots>).*(?=<\/carrots>)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DnCBlC/3)

Comment: this will fail if there is another </carrots> down the string

Comment: need to add another handle, if there is multiple carrots on the string

Comment: That is correct. In that case you should make it lazy using `.*?`

Comment: Thanks for this very simple and intuitive solution